# Subclipse problem: changing the name of a package

Tags: eclipse, svn, eclipse-plugin

Every time I change a package name or move some source code folder, I get "out of date" errors when trying to commit on SVN with Subclipse (plugin for Eclipse). It's amazingly annoying and I always have to spend additional 20 minutes trying to think of a solution how to solve that. Does anyone have similar problems? How do you solve them? Is there a way to force commit something (to say to commit and not pay attention to non-updated files)?

Comment: How do you rename/move the packages? Do you use `Refactor -> Rename` and `Refactor -> Move` from the context menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem. Unfortunately I have not found out the reason.At first I thought this happens because of incorrect commit order for packages, subpackages and classes. It seems the problem occurs only for projects with more then one developer involved. I always do Update after deleting any package and before commit. This always helps me.

Comment: I'm the only one commiting there, that's the thing.